# c++ code blocks error

Tags: c++, compilation, codeblocks

First: My English is not that good yours is. Excuse me.

I'm using Ubuntu (I don't know if this is important) and I had issues with Code::Blocks since I started to use it. But I fixed them by re-opening the program. But now, I get a really crazy error when compiling the code. I included a file just like usual:
 `#include "GameObjectUtility.h"`

and I used the class "GameObjectUtility" to declare a member object, just like this:

```
class GameObject
{
    std::vector<GameObjectUtility> uts;
    // Error here: 
    // GameObjectUtility was not declared in this scope
}
```

So, is this my fault or is there something buggy with Code::Blocks?
And, additionally, is there a way of saying to the Linker: First execute this file and then the other?

Thank you for your answers!

EDIT: .h and .ccp file GameObjectUtility:

So this is GameObjectUtility.h:

```
#ifndef GAMEOBJECTUTILITY_H
#define GAMEOBJECTUTILITY_H

#include <string>

#include "Collision.h"

class GameObjectUtility
{
public:
GameObjectUtility();
virtual ~GameObjectUtility();

virtual void Update() = 0;
virtual void LateUpdate() = 0;
virtual void FixedUpdate() = 0;

static void SendMsg(std::string msg);
protected:
private:
    virtual void GetMsg(std::string msg) = 0;
};

#endif // GAMEOBJECTUTILITY_H
```

And in GameObjectUtility.cpp are just two empty definitions of constructor and destructor

Comment: How about having a forward declaration of GameObjectUtility ?

Comment: Did you mean something like 'class GameObjectUtility;' ?

Comment: can you show what `GameObjectUtility` looks like from `GameObjectUtility.h`. I am suspecting that you are getting this error as its definition might be present in `GameObjectUtility.cpp`.

Comment: EDIT: I'm posting as answer, because newline does not work in comments(?)

Answer (score 1):

Since `class GameObjectUtility` is pure virtual, you cannot instantiate it.

You can only store `std::vector<GameObjectUtility*>` in class `GameObject`.

Comment: It's because the vector may construct an instance of GameObjectUtility if it directly uses that. It's a better idea to use a pointer like timrau adivsed because that can be just NULLed ,when needed.

Comment: But is says, it is not declared in this scope, like i forgot including it, but i did.... And the include file compiles fine..

Comment: If i do a declaration of GameObjectUtility in GameObject.h it works, but what is wrong including it as usual?